# Selenium finding element

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to find the element but I'm getting an error
This is my code:

```
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //String parentHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create Account")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    //String currentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
    //driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
    //String currentURL=;
    //(currentURL);

    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("9051902811");


    driver.close();
    //driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);

    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException nsee){
        System.out.println(nsee.toString());
  }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

And I am getting the exception:

Unable to locate element "method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/input"} Command duration or timeout: 89 milliseconds

please help...

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the field that you are trying to reach?
Also make it sleep for 2 seconds before trying to find an element, selenium has the ability to go to quick sometimes

Comment: @Decypher that is _horrible_ advice.. There is a reason why Selenium has [implicit and explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).  OP - do though show the HTML of the field you're trying to interact with

Comment: impli en explicit waits sometimes do go to quick, just as sleep sometimes aswell. It's a known issue of selenium , putting the timer higher is just for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have shown it is hard to say exactly what the issue is. It could be a couple different things.

1) Does the element exist? If you show the html this could be answered very quickly.

Xpaths are very brittle and very much error prone.
Try to use a different selector if at all possible, id and class are much more reliable.
Here is the link to the [By](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("keys");
driver.findElement(By.className("className")).sendKeys("keys");
```

Something that is more concrete, and when content is added that changes the structure, it doesn't break the tests, xpaths wil certainly make your tests brittle.

---

2) Is the input box loaded yet?

Selenium sometimes will try to find an element that isn't loaded yet. [Explicit Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) will help solve this issue, you can use these waits along with [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for an element to be visible, clickable, not visible, among other things. **Do Not** use thread.sleep unless there is no other choice(which there probably is).

The below code can be used to wait for the element to be visible.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
            .xpath(xpath)));
```

You can use this to ensure the element is visible by xpath, but if possible you should consider using a different selector, one that won't make your test very visible. If the element does not have an id/class, you can anchor the xpath to a more reliable selector as well, to reduce some brittleness.
I will be happy to provide more info, if you provide the html.